# Flutter Plugin's 3rd party integration for code coverage, build passing, provider, gitter etc

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I have developed Flutter Plugin for developers to help common feature implementation. Here is plugin reference links.

**GitHub**: https://github.com/techgrains/TGFramework-Flutter

**Pub.dev**: https://pub.dev/packages/techgrains

I have observed many people having additional links for automation and integration at the top of document as several capsule items.

**Question**: Am I missing anything major as standard plugin implementation?

My goal is to give 'all in one' best plugin to reduce common headache and time consuming effort while developing any Flutter app.

Please suggest: 3rd party integration for code coverage, build passing, provider, gitter etc. which most of the plugin developers are relying upon.

Comment: This is really more of a question about Dart and Flutter's package ecosystem than a technical how-to question. I would recommend posting it to the FlutterDev Google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/flutter-dev) rather than here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. Following up there.